# What is the use of esconfig.xml found in the vendor\magento\module-elasticsearch\etc directory?

Tags: magento2.3.3, elasticsearch

Does any one having any idea about `esconfig.xml` file exists in the `vendor\magento\module-elasticsearch\etc` directory?

As per name suggests, it looks like it is related with words configuration with ElasticSearch but can we configure `max_clause` and `mapping` related configurations in that file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Elasticsearch:etc/esconfig.xsd">
    <stemmer>
        <type>stemmer</type>
        <default>english</default>
        <de_DE>german</de_DE>
        <en_US>english</en_US>
        <es_ES>spanish</es_ES>
        <fr_FR>french</fr_FR>
        <nl_NL>dutch</nl_NL>
        <pt_BR>portuguese</pt_BR>
        <zh_Hans_CN>cjk</zh_Hans_CN>
    </stemmer>
    <stopwords_file>
        <default>stopwords.csv</default>
        <de_DE>stopwords_de_DE.csv</de_DE>
        <en_US>stopwords_en_US.csv</en_US>
        <es_ES>stopwords_es_ES.csv</es_ES>
        <fr_FR>stopwords_fr_FR.csv</fr_FR>
        <nl_NL>stopwords_nl_NL.csv</nl_NL>
        <pt_BR>stopwords_pt_BR.csv</pt_BR>
        <zh_Hans_CN>stopwords_zh_Hans_CN.csv</zh_Hans_CN>
    </stopwords_file>
</config>
```